# BCL and FCL - both are NameSpaces?

Tags: .net

I need a clarity regarding class libraries.
`Base Class Libraries` and `Framework Class Libraries` both are comes under namespaces-I mean can we call both are namespaces? if not which one we can call as a `namespace` and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not namespaces. A namespace is something like `System`, `System.IO` or `System.Collections.Generic`. The libraries contain types that are *in* namespaces, but the libraries aren't namespaces themselves.